# Python pandas cannot read utf-8 file with foreign characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, utf-8

I am trying to merge tsv files using pandas but cannot get pandas to return the file contents correctly. My tsv files contain Italian and pandas fails at accented characters like à.

My tsv:

```
EN  IT
and now a adesso
can i change the brightness Posso modificare la luminosità
```

Following  block returns an empty result set

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.read_csv('IT.tsv', delimiter='\t', encoding='utf-8')
print test
```

If I remove the à from the end of the third line, it reads just fine. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Shouldn't encoding be standard python encoding (ie 'utf_8', not 'utf-8')?

Comment: @abolotnov `utf_8` is the name of the encoding module (module names can't have dashes) but `"utf-8"` as an encoding name is acceptable.

Comment: The example worked for me with python 2.7.6 on linux and a utf-8 terminal. Are you on windows? What does `sys.stdin.encoding` say? ...not that it will help me that much...

Comment: Yes, I am on Windows, python 2.7.10. I am new to python and not sure what to do with `sys.stdin.encoding`, do you mind telling a bit more? For the record, utf_8 did not make a difference.

Comment: Do `import sys`
`sys.getdefaultencoding()`

Comment: That returns `ascii`

Comment: If it fails, the file's encoding is not utf-8. Try reading it with `latin-1`, and *inspect the results* since it'll probably succeed even if the encoding is incorrect.

Comment: On windows on a west european language machine, I would try `encoding='cp1252'`. If it does not work, `encoding='latin1'` will accept any byte. Simply it may not convert everything as expected if the real encoding is not Latin1...